# Node.js - Angular - MongoDB - for `userid` , get `username`

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have such mongoose.Schema:

**User.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({

    username: String,
    password:  String,      
    email:  String,      
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema, 'users');
```

**product.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({

    userid: {type:String, required: true},
    product_name: {type:String, required: true}     
});

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('products', ProductSchema, 'products');
```

**method:**

```
exports.selectUsersProductsCount = function (req, res, next) {

  Product.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:{userid:"$userid" }, count:{$sum:1} }   }
],
function(err, result) {
    if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err }); }
        res.status(201).json({
          success: true,
          data: result
    });
    console.log(result);
})

}
```

result:

```
[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' }, count: 3 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' }, count: 1 } ]
```

I want the `username` field to be displayed as well. I do not know how to use `join`. Counts correctly, but does not display the username field.

How to correct the `aggregate` method to display:
**userid, username, count**

```
[ { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112', username: 'Jon Alon' }, count: 3 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7', username: 'Jonson Con' }, count: 1 } ]
```

examples data:

**Product**

```
{
    _id:O bjectId(5ab7da972ade533790268f47),
    userid:"5ab655bbb94733156c438112",
    product_name:"gs",
    __v:0
},{
    _id: ObjectId(5ab7daa92ade533790268f48),
    userid:"5ab655bbb94733156c438112",
    product_name:"dg",
    __v:0 
}
```

**User**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(5ab655bbb94733156c438112),
    username: "rrrr",
    email:"rrrr",
    __v:0 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the $[lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-mergeobjects) function to achieve that but you need to have some property in common between the 2 collections.
You would need to add userId on UserSchema or some other property so you could "join"

In your example u could try

```
db.product.aggregate([ {$lookup:{ from: "user", localField: "ObjectId(userid)", foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)", as: "username" }}, {"$group" : {_id:{userid:"$userid", username : "$username" }, count:{$sum:1} } } ])
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167684/discussion-on-answer-by-graciano-node-js-angular-mongodb-for-userid-ge).

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

```
products.aggregate([

  {$lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "ObjectId(userid)",
    foreignField: "ObjectId(_id)",
    as: "users"
  }},


{ "$group" :
  {
    _id: { userid: "$userid" },
    name: { $last: "$users.username" } ,
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}, {$sort: {"_id.userid":  1}}

  ], function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if(err){ res.status(400).json({ success: false, message:'Error processing request '+ err }); }
          res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: result
      });  
    }
  );
}
```

returns:

```
[ { _id: { userid: '5ab425c6f5bff145304092f7' },
    name: [ 'cccc', 'rrrr', 'zzzz' ],
    count: 3 },
  { _id: { userid: '5ab655bbb94733156c438112' },
    name: [ 'cccc', 'rrrr', 'zzzz' ],
    count: 1 },
  { _id: { userid: '5aba7e8c045115340496becd' },
    name: [ 'cccc', 'rrrr', 'zzzz' ],
    count: 2 } ]
```